# Mapping ValueQ over a list of symbols gives answer different from direct evaluation

Tags: evaluation, symbols

If I start with a symbol `q` that I've assigned a value to,

```
q = 0;
```

and one, `x`, that I haven't, I get different answers from `ValueQ` depending on how I call `ValueQ`.  If I map `ValueQ` over a list,

```
Map[ ValueQ, {q,x} ]
```

Mathematica returns `{False, False}`.  If I apply `ValueQ` directly, however,

```
{ValueQ[q], ValueQ[x]}
```

Mathematica returns a different answer, `{True, False}`.  I've tried

```
{Names["q"], Names["x"]}
```

which returns `{{q},{}}` before evaluating the two `ValueQ` calls, and `{{q},{x}}` after the calls.  There's obviously some sort of side effect from the call to `ValueQ` taking place behind the scenes. If I quit the kernel to start with a clean slate each time, however, and reverse the order in which I call the two versions (`Map` or no `Map`) I get the same results.

This is troubling behavior.  What's going on?

I'm using Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Linux x86 (64-bit).

Comment: Please, see Section "Properties & Relations" in Documentation on `ValueQ`. The effect I suppose is concerned with `HoldAll` attribute of `ValueQ`, so that `ValueQ/@Unevaluated[{q, x}]` gives right answer `{True, False}`.

Answer (score 7):

`Map` is evaluating its arguments, so you end up with `ValueQ[0]` (`False`) instead of `ValueQ[q]]` (`True`);

```
In[3]:= Map[ValueQ, Unevaluated[{q, x}]]

Out[3]= {True, False}
```

Comment: That makes sense now.  I've seen other functions with `HoldAll` attribute behave the same way.

Answer (score 3):

There're actually 2 issues in your question. One is the evaluation control problem, this has been explained by [Brett Champion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/69/brett-champion) and [Alx](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134107/mapping-valueq-over-a-list-of-symbols-gives-answer-different-from-direct-evaluat#comment361837_134107). The other issue is:

Why `{Names["q"], Names["x"]}` returns `{{"q"}, {}}` before the `ValueQ` calls?

The answer is: `ValueQ` isn't relevant at all, the key point is, the symbol `x` has **appeared** in the code `Map[ValueQ, {q, x}]` so it's created.

A simpler way to reproduce the issue is:

```
Remove[x]
Names["x"]
(* {} *)
x;
Names["x"]
(* {"x"} *)
```